# C# Stackoverflow in recursive deleting directory operation

Tags: c#, stack-overflow, delete-file, delete-directory

I'm currently rewriting a file deletion tool with safe deleting algorithm and stuff.
Wenn I'm trying to browse through a directory recursivly and to delete all files in there and all subdirs etc. the debugger will throw a stackoverflow exception.

```
   private void wipeFile(string file)
   {
        bool ret = false;
        switch (m_algo)
        {
            case Algorithms.fastAlgo:
                ret = FastWipe.WipeFile(file);
                break;
            case Algorithms.safeAlgo:
                ret = CleanWipe.WipeFile(file, m_timesToWrite);
                break;
        }
        handleFileWiped(file, DateTime.Now, ret);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Wipes a directory recursively
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="directory">Given subdir</param>
    private void deepWipe(string directory)
    {
        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(directory))
        {
            wipeFile(file);
        }
        foreach (string subdir in Directory.GetDirectories(directory))
        {
            deepWipe(directory);
        }
        try
        {
            Directory.Delete(directory);
            handleDirectoryWiped(directory, DateTime.Now, true);
        }
        catch { handleDirectoryWiped(directory, DateTime.Now, false); }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
 foreach (string subdir in Directory.GetDirectories(directory))
 {
     deepWipe(directory);
 }
```

to:

```
 foreach (string subdir in Directory.GetDirectories(directory))
 {
     deepWipe(subdir);
 }
```